# SML: Boolean function

Tags: list, boolean, sml

While learning the SML, I came up with the following question. Look at this example:

```
fun check (elem,myList) =
let
  fun check1 elem [] = fn (x,_,_) => elem > x
  fun check2 elem [] = fn (_,y,_) => elem < y
in
  if check1 andalso check2 then 1 else 0
end
```

The probem is that IF THEN rule does not work here. Why? As far as I understand check1 and check2 should return BOOL value, which allows using IF THEN. I tried to declare local variables, but this didn´t help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`check1` and `check2` are functions, not `bool` values. Presumably, you'll want to apply them to something?

Comment: The function ´check´ should return just 0 or 1 depending on the result of Logical AND for check1 and check2. This function can be compiled only with:
in
  check1
end. But this is not what I need.

Comment: Ok, I understood the problem. The logic of this function is absolutely different from the one that I was thinking about.